# How to identify bezel less android phone programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I identify bezel-less Android Smartphone? In my application I have one Bottom menu that is not visible in bazel less smartphone. Can somebody guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the screen resolution by this code,

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int widthContentView = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
int heightContentView = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
```

if the ratio of height and width is 18:9 or  2:1 than it should be a bazel less device.

Comment: Some device does not have ratio of 18:9 then also It have soft back press in screen.

Comment: can you give example of some of these devices?

Comment: Motorola G5 and In Emulator Nexus 4 also showing soft back at bottom

Comment: do you mean by On Screen Buttons?

Comment: yes, some device have soft back press button at bottom, Motorola G5 have that and One Plus device also have that but both devices have different ratio

Comment: My bottom menu is visible in motorola g5 but it is not working on one plus devices.

Comment: can you please tell me what oneplus device you are talking about. because in moto g5 the screen ration is 1.77. which is less than 2.xx so there is plenty of difference between resolution ratio of a bezel less device(note 8) and motog5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163785/discussion-between-nik-and-jitendra-purohit).

Answer (score 0):

@jitendra purohit's answer is correct. Here I have improved his answer to get ratio:

```
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int widthContentView = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        int heightContentView = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        heightContentView = heightContentView + getNavigationBarHeight();

        if(heightContentView/widthContentView == 2){
            Log.v("Bazel less Device","Bazel less");
        //if the ratio of height and width is 18:9 or 2:1 than it should be a bazel less device.
        }




    private int getNavigationBarHeight() {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```